# How to get text from VTE using PyGObject ( Gtk3 in Python)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygobject, vte

In the Gnome documentation of vte is described the method `get_text` : [vte_terminl_get_text](http://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/VteTerminal.html#vte-terminal-get-text).
Executing `dir()` on `vte.Terminal` ( Gtk2) I can see that the method get_text is available, instead in `Vte.Terminal` (Gtk3) that method doesn't exist.
Is there an alternative way to get text from vte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems you hit a [bug in Vte GObject Introspection binding](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684833).